# Generate all possible permutations of multi-type collection

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

Can I use `itertools` to generate all possible permutations of a multi-type dictionary? It's hard for me to figure out which `itertools` function/s I can use to achieve this. Do you know?

Below is an example of what I want to achieve

```
# Give the below Dict to a itertools function...
tuner_params = {
    'darken': (True, False),
    'hue_quantize': (True, False),
    'quantize': (True, False),
    'blur': (range(1,25), range(1,25)),
    'h_samples': range(2, 20),
    'v_samples': range(2, 20), 
    'offset': range(0.05, 0.9, 0.05), 
    'kernel': (range(1,25), range(1,25))
}

# And get something like...desired output is all possible permuations of the above dict values, for eg
[{
    'darken': True,
    'hue_quantize': True,
    'quantize': True,
    'blur': (1,1),
    'h_samples': 2,
    'v_samples': 2, 
    'offset': 0.05, 
    'kernel': (1,1)
},
{
    'darken': False,
    'hue_quantize': True,
    'quantize': True,
    'blur': (1,1),
    'h_samples': 2,
    'v_samples': 2, 
    'offset': 0.05, 
    'kernel': (1,1)
}
...
{
    'darken': False,
    'hue_quantize': False,
    'quantize': False,
    'blur': (25,25),
    'h_samples': 20,
    'v_samples': 20, 
    'offset': 0.9, 
    'kernel': (25,25)
}]
```

Comment: `'darken': True or False` ? Do you mean `[True, False]` ? Also how does `'h_samples': range(2, 20),` translate to `'h_samples': 2,` and `'h_samples': 20,`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using either

- a dict comprehension and nested `for` clauses
- `itertools.product` on the various data collections you have -- generate a list of the values, and then assign them to the desired dict keys.

Do note that you have to learn a little more about how to specify an iterable.  For instance, `True or False` is simply the Boolean value `True`; you need `(True, False)` to allow `product` to properly iterate over the values.  Similarly, I think you'll want to convert your `range` iterators to `list` type.

Is that enough to get you moving in the direction you need?

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you elaborate on "convert your range iterators to list type."? I'm not sure how I would implement that?

Comment: list(range(1,25)) -- what you gave is a tuple with two generators in it, not quite what you want.